# Can't reconnect my device to wifi after the deauthentication attack was over

Tags: linux, kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am a beginner with ethical hacking, and I was trying the deauthentication attack on my device from a hotspot of a mobile device.

`aireplay-ng --deauth 4 -a xxxxx -c xxxxxx wlan0`

after doing this after the command gets executed fully , I try to reconnect my device to the hotspot of the mobile device but I am not able to reconnect and it still behaves like it is receiving the deauthentication attack. It reconnects after 5 mins of wait. This should not happen as I sent only 4 packets??

I am running kali linux on virtual box.

`ifconfig` :

```
eth0 no wireless extensions.
wlan0 IEEE 802.11 Mode:Monitor Frequency:2.412 GHz Tx-Power=20 dBm
Retry short limit:7 RTS thr=2347 B Fragment thr:off 
Power Management:off lo no wireless extensions
```

`ip link show` :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 
link/ether 08:00:27:7b:7d:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DORMANT mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000 
link/ieee802.11/radiotap 4a:7c:c6:0d:71:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff –
```

Comment: Run these commands... `iwconfig` `ip link show` give us output of it..!

Comment: link to ss of these commands https://ibb.co/wWSfBkc

Comment: [Please read it](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: if I comment the whole code it will exceed the limit

Comment: No!. It won't you can write 30000 words in question or answer..!

Comment: I said to edit question... Anyway, I have requested an edit....! And, now [read the answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/449077)

Answer (score 0):

After searching little bit I found some related question and links for you.

1. [What does mean DORMANT mode in ip link show wlan0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194048/what-does-mean-dormant-mode-in-ip-link-show-wlan0)
2. [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362438)
3. [No internet connection but connected to wifi](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?34217-No-internet-connection-but-connected-to-wifi)(This may not be helpful for you).

If at the output :

```
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DORMANT mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000  
link/ieee802.11/radiotap 4a:7c:c6:0d:71:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff –
```

Your `state` and `mode` is set to `DORMANT`. You have to change state and mode both. So, I think you should restart `NetworkManager` in terminal

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

I found following code from UbuntuForums

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

`network-manager` doesn't work than try with `NetworkManager`. If these doesn't work also than you try following code

```
ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

As I think you are not professional nor intermediate to Kali/Linux. That's why I will tell you use any friendly linux distro. Kali isn't for beginner.

Most of people don't answers when they see [kali-linux](/questions/tagged/kali-linux) tag. [People won't come to help and mostly they will ignore](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361).